# error during "import ibm_db"

Tags: python, db2

I am getting this error !

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/e****/RRR/RRR_Success.py", line 37, in ?
    import ibm_db
ImportError: libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Above error indicate DB2 client libraries is not in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, Please set /home/../path/to/sqllib/lib in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. For more info you can go through http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.gs.doc/doc/c0006321.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

From my experience LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not needed. I got this problem on a system where the python db2 odbc driver and db2 server were on the same machine.

First check if there is only one libdb2.so.1 file on the system.
find / -name libdb2.so.1

If there are two, chances are they are different, so check the md5sum.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/db2-odbc.conf
/opt/ibm/db2/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib
[root@localhost ~]# ll /opt/ibm/db2/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1
[root@localhost ~]# ll /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/libdb2.so.1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 bin bin 42685547 Dec 15 08:49 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/libdb2.so.1

[root@localhost ~]# md5sum /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/libdb2.so.1
ffca929b98201e3934e9625d1480890f  /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/libdb2.so.1
[root@localhost ~]# md5sum /opt/ibm/db2/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1
a1247f1582eb1bd2fc248b3901812951  /opt/ibm/db2/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The files are different, you can control which file is linked by modifying ldconfig.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ll /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
total 24
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  17 Feb  9  2012 atlas-x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  28 Dec 15 08:50 db2.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  36 Dec 15 09:07 db2-odbc.conf
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 324 Jun  6  2014 kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  17 Feb  3  2014 mysql-x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  22 Jul 18  2011 qt-x86_64.conf
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I removed the db2.conf file from this folder, and ran ldconfig, it then started to work.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mv /etc/ld.so.conf.d/db2.conf mahesh/
[root@localhost ~]# ldconfig
```

Note that the db2 client from db2inst1 still works and this is where the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set.

```
[root@localhost ~]# su - db2inst1
[db2inst1@localhost ~]$ db2 connect to dbname

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = dbname

[db2inst1@localhost ~]$ env | grep LIBRARY
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib32
[db2inst1@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for a docker image:

```
WORKDIR /home/db2_cli_odbc_driver
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get --assume-yes install \
       wget && \
    wget https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz -O odbc_cli.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf odbc_cli.tar.gz && rm odbc_cli.tar.gz && \
    echo /home/db2_cli_odbc_driver/clidriver/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/db2.conf && \
    ldconfig && \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove wget && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV IBM_DB_HOME=/home/db2_cli_odbc_driver/clidriver
```

In order words,

- download the driver
- unpack it
- create a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/db2.conf` file pointing to the target folder
- run `ldconfig`
- set the `IBM_DB_HOME` variable before installing the python package

Comment: I was having this issue on a django app in CentOS7. Starting my server wouldnt find libdb2.so.1 and crashed my application. Here is a script version that worked https://pastebin.com/f0MGevH6 . Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

(Re)install [`ibm-db`](http://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/)

Comment: I don't know if ibm-db reinstalls the db2 client, but just reinstalling python files should not fix the problem. Since this is related to the c++ files linking.